# Neural Network in Swift

Tags: swift, ai, neural-network

This is my first Neural Network, specifically a multilayer feed forward neural network that uses back-propagation for training, and I plan on using it for a multitude of projects. I started with the XOR function and now I'm moving to OCR. This network, as far as I know, can also be used for deep learning. I chose Swift because it's the language I'm most comfortable with. However, I may convert it to C++ for learning purposes.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could make this code more bullet proof, improve the quality, improve performance, more robust/versatile, etc.?

Also, is this a good style to use? Meaning is it common to use all class functions? I feel like this would reduce, if not eliminate, any side effects and makes the code more thread safe? I can easily whip up some instance methods that call the class methods, then in turn store the weights, activations, derivatives, etc..

It seems like it's pretty fast compared to other neural networks that I've downloaded and compared it to (only 2 in all honesty). However, as this is my first ANN, I'm not sure what "fast" is defined as. When attempting to train and test it with the MNIST dataset on a late 2015 iMac 4GHz Intel Core i7 Processor with 8GB DDR3 the results are as follows:

### Topology

**Number Of Layers:** 3 
**Number of Input Neurons:** 784 
**Number of Hidden Neurons:** 20 
**Number of Output Neurons:** 10

### Training

**Epochs:** 100 
**Final Cost:** 0.00529893 
**Cost Function:** Mean Squared 
**Activation Function:** Sigmoid 
**Number Of Training Examples:** 60,000 
**Elapsed Time:** 24 minutes and 6 seconds

### Testing

**Number of Testing Examples:** 10,000 
**Number of Correct Predictions:** 9,297 
**Ratio:** 92.97%

*Quick side note: I'm new to optimization as well but, it's definitely something I would like to be better at!*

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions! Please be as harsh as you deem necessary! Also, if any more information is needed feel free to let me know.

**EDIT 1:**

I doubt this is applicable here but, I would like to implement some type of "live" testing where the user could draw a number on the screen, feed it forward, and get a predication.

Do I need to normalize the image the same way as the MNIST data? (e.g. normalize to fit in a 20x20 image while preserving the aspect ratio, center in a 28x28 image, and compute the center of mass. Then, translate the image so as to position this point at the center of the 28x28 field.) The only problem with that is I don't know the anti-aliasing technique used by the normalization algorithm to get the grey scale levels (hopefully I could just email Yann LeCun and find out though).

Here's the GitHub incase anyone finds that easier to read: [JPSNeuralNetwork](https://github.com/MotivatedCreation/JPSNeuralNetwork/tree/master/JPSNeuralNetwork/JPSFramework)

**JPSNeuralNetwork.swift**

```
//
//  JPSNeuralNetwork.swift
//
//  Created by Jonathan Sullivan on 4/4/17.
//

import Foundation
import Accelerate

public protocol JPSNeuralNetworkDelegate
{
    func network(costDidChange cost: Float)
    func network(progressDidChange progress: Float)
    func network(overallProgressDidChange progress: Float)
}

public class JPSNeuralNetwork
{
    private typealias FeedForwardResult = (inputs: Matrix, activations: Matrix, activationRates: Matrix)
    
    private class func cost(costFunction: JPSNeuralNetworkCostFunction, activations: Matrix, targetOutputs: Matrix) -> Scalar
    {
        var cost: Scalar = 0
        
        for (activation, targetOutput) in zip(activations, targetOutputs) {
            cost += costFunction.cost(forOutputs: activation, targetOutputs: targetOutput)
        }
        
        cost /= Scalar(targetOutputs.count)
        
        return cost
    }
    
    private class func weights(forTopology topology: [Int]) -> Matrix
    {
        var weights = Matrix()
        
        var previousNumberOfInputs = topology[0]
        
        for neuronCount in topology[1..<topology.count]
        {
            // Plus one for the bias weight.
            
            let neuronWeights = JPSNeuralNetworkLayer.randomWeights(neuronCount: neuronCount, inputCount: previousNumberOfInputs + 1)
            weights.append(neuronWeights)
            
            previousNumberOfInputs = neuronCount
        }
        
        return weights
    }
    
    public class func feedForward(topology: [Int], activationFunction: JPSNeuralNetworkActivationFunction, inputs: Vector, weights: Matrix) -> Vector {
        return JPSNeuralNetwork.feedForward(topology: topology, activationFunction: activationFunction, inputs: inputs, weights: weights).activations.last!
    }
    
    private class func feedForward(topology: [Int], activationFunction: JPSNeuralNetworkActivationFunction, inputs: Vector, weights: Matrix) -> FeedForwardResult
    {
        var previousActivations = inputs
        
        var networkInputs = Matrix()
        var networkActivations = Matrix()
        var networkActivationRates = Matrix()
        
        // Ignore the input layer as it's just a place holder.
        
        for (neuronCount, layerWeights) in zip(topology[1..<topology.count], weights)
        {
            // Append one for the bias input.
            
            var layerInputs = previousActivations
            layerInputs.append(1)
            networkInputs.append(layerInputs)
            
            let feedForward = JPSNeuralNetworkLayer.feedForward(neuronCount: neuronCount, activationFunction: activationFunction, inputs: layerInputs, weights: layerWeights)
            
            previousActivations = feedForward.activations
            
            networkActivations.append(previousActivations)
            networkActivationRates.append(feedForward.activationRates)
        }
        
        return (networkInputs, networkActivations, networkActivationRates)
    }
    
    private class func outputGradientFor(costFunction: JPSNeuralNetworkCostFunction, activations: Vector, activationRates: Vector, targetOutputs: Vector) -> Vector
    {
        var gradient = Vector()
        
        for (activationRate, (activation, targetOutput)) in zip(activationRates, zip(activations, targetOutputs))
        {
            let costRate = costFunction.derivative(OfOutput: activation, targetOutput: targetOutput)
            let error = (costRate * activationRate)
            gradient.append(error)
        }
        
        return gradient
    }
    
    private class func gradientFor(costFunction: JPSNeuralNetworkCostFunction, activations: Matrix, activationRates: Matrix, weights: Matrix, targetOutputs: Vector) -> Matrix
    {
        let reversedWeights = weights.reversed()
        var reversedActivations = (activations.reversed() as Matrix)
        var reversedActivationRates = (activationRates.reversed() as Matrix)
        
        let outputLayerActivations = reversedActivations.removeFirst()
        let outputLayerActivationRates = reversedActivationRates.removeFirst()
        var previousGradient = JPSNeuralNetwork.outputGradientFor(costFunction: costFunction, activations: outputLayerActivations, activationRates: outputLayerActivationRates, targetOutputs: targetOutputs)
        
        var gradient = Matrix()
        gradient.append(previousGradient)
        
        for (layerActivationRates, (layerActivations, layerWeights)) in zip(reversedActivationRates, zip(reversedActivations, reversedWeights))
        {
            previousGradient = JPSNeuralNetworkLayer.gradientFor(activations: layerActivations, activationRates: layerActivationRates, weights: layerWeights, gradient: previousGradient)
            
            gradient.append(previousGradient)
        }
        
        return gradient.reversed()
    }
    
    private class func updateWeights(learningRate: Float, inputs: Matrix, weights: Matrix, gradient: Matrix) -> Matrix
    {
        var newWeights = Matrix()
        
        for ((layerInputs, layerWeights), layerGradient) in zip(zip(inputs, weights), gradient)
        {
            let newLayerWeights = JPSNeuralNetworkLayer.updateWeights(learningRate: learningRate, inputs: layerInputs, weights: layerWeights, gradient: layerGradient)
            newWeights.append(newLayerWeights)
        }
        
        return newWeights
    }
    
    private class func backpropagate(learningRate: Float, costFunction: JPSNeuralNetworkCostFunction, inputs: Matrix, weights: Matrix, activations: Matrix, activationRates: Matrix, targetOutput: Vector) -> Matrix
    {
        let gradient = JPSNeuralNetwork.gradientFor(costFunction: costFunction, activations: activations, activationRates: activationRates, weights: weights, targetOutputs: targetOutput)
        
        return JPSNeuralNetwork.updateWeights(learningRate: learningRate, inputs: inputs, weights: weights, gradient: gradient)
    }
    
    public class func train(delegate: JPSNeuralNetworkDelegate?, topology: [Int], epochs: Int, learningRate: Float, activationFunction: JPSNeuralNetworkActivationFunction, costFunction: JPSNeuralNetworkCostFunction, trainingInputs: Matrix, targetOutputs: Matrix) -> Matrix
    {
        var weights = JPSNeuralNetwork.weights(forTopology: topology)
        
        for epoch in 0..<epochs
        {
            var activations = Matrix()
            
            for (index, (inputs, targetOutput)) in zip(trainingInputs, targetOutputs).enumerated()
            {
                let progress = (Float(index + 1) / Float(targetOutputs.count))
                delegate?.network(progressDidChange: progress)
                
                let overallProgress = ((Float(epoch) + progress) / Float(epochs))
                delegate?.network(overallProgressDidChange: overallProgress)
                
                let feedForward: FeedForwardResult = JPSNeuralNetwork.feedForward(topology: topology, activationFunction: activationFunction, inputs: inputs, weights: weights)
                activations.append(feedForward.activations.last!)
                
                weights = JPSNeuralNetwork.backpropagate(learningRate: learningRate, costFunction: costFunction, inputs: feedForward.inputs, weights: weights, activations: feedForward.activations, activationRates: feedForward.activationRates, targetOutput: targetOutput)
            }
            
            let cost = JPSNeuralNetwork.cost(costFunction: costFunction, activations: activations, targetOutputs: targetOutputs)
            delegate?.network(costDidChange: cost)
        }
        
        return weights
    }
}
```

**JPSNeuralNetworkLayer.swift**

```
//
//  JPSNeuralNetworkLayer.swift
//
//  Created by Jonathan Sullivan on 4/4/17.
//

import Foundation
import Accelerate


public class JPSNeuralNetworkLayer
{
    /**
     Used to generate a random weights for all neurons.
     */
    public class func randomWeights(neuronCount: Int, inputCount: Int) -> Vector
    {
        var layerWeights = Vector()
        
        for _ in 0..<neuronCount
        {
            let neuronWeights = JPSNeuralNetworkNeuron.randomWeights(inputCount: inputCount)
            layerWeights.append(contentsOf: neuronWeights)
        }
        
        return layerWeights
    }
    
    /**
     Used to feed the inputs and weights forward and calculate the weighted input and activation.
     This method also precalculates the activation rate for use later on and to reduce the number of
     calculations.
     
     weightedInput = sum(x[i] * w[i])
     activation = sigma(weightedInput[j])
     activationRate = sigma'(activation[j])
     */
    public class func feedForward(neuronCount: Int, activationFunction: JPSNeuralNetworkActivationFunction, inputs: Vector, weights: Vector) -> (activations: Vector, activationRates: Vector)
    {
        var activations = Vector(repeating: 0, count: neuronCount)
        
        vDSP_mmul(weights, 1,
                  inputs, 1,
                  &activations, 1,
                  vDSP_Length(neuronCount), 1,
                  vDSP_Length(inputs.count))
        
        activations = activations.map({
            return activationFunction.activation($0)
        })
        
        let activationRates = activations.map({
            return activationFunction.derivative($0)
        })
        
        return (activations, activationRates)
    }
    
    /**
     Used to calculate the error gradient for each neuron.
     */
    public class func gradientFor(activations: Vector, activationRates: Vector, weights: Vector, gradient: Vector) -> Vector
    {
        var layerGradient = Vector(repeating: 0, count: activations.count)
        
        vDSP_mmul(gradient, 1,
                  weights, 1,
                  &layerGradient, 1,
                  1, vDSP_Length(activations.count),
                  vDSP_Length(gradient.count))
        
        vDSP_vmul(layerGradient, 1,
                  activationRates, 1,
                  &layerGradient, 1,
                  vDSP_Length(layerGradient.count))
        
        return layerGradient
    }
    
    /**
     Used to generate update each neurons weights on a per neuron error basis given the input.
     */
    public class func updateWeights(learningRate: Float, inputs: Vector, weights: Vector, gradient: Vector) -> Vector
    {
        var nagativeLearningRate = -learningRate
        var scaledGradient = Vector(repeating: 0, count: gradient.count)
        
        vDSP_vsmul(gradient, 1,
                   &nagativeLearningRate,
                   &scaledGradient, 1,
                   vDSP_Length(gradient.count))
        
        var scaledInputs = Vector(repeating: 0, count: weights.count)
        
        vDSP_mmul(scaledGradient, 1,
                  inputs, 1,
                  &scaledInputs, 1,
                  vDSP_Length(scaledGradient.count), vDSP_Length(inputs.count),
                  1)

        var layerWeights = Vector(repeating: 0, count: weights.count)
        
        vDSP_vadd(weights, 1,
                  scaledInputs, 1,
                  &layerWeights, 1,
                  vDSP_Length(weights.count))
        
        return layerWeights
    }
}
```

**JPSNeuralNetworkNeuron.swift**

```
//
//  JPSNeuralNetworkNeuron.swift
//
//  Created by Jonathan Sullivan on 4/4/17.
//

import Foundation

public typealias Scalar = Float
public typealias Vector = [Scalar]
public typealias Matrix = [Vector]

public enum JPSNeuralNetworkCostFunction: Int
{
    case meanSquared = 0
    case crossEntropy = 1
    
    func derivative(OfOutput output: Scalar, targetOutput: Scalar) -> Scalar
    {
        switch self
        {
        case .crossEntropy:
            return (output - targetOutput) / ((1 - output) * output)
            
        case .meanSquared:
            fallthrough
            
        default:
            return (output - targetOutput)
        }
    }
    
    func cost(forOutputs outputs: Vector, targetOutputs: Vector) -> Scalar
    {
        switch self
        {
        case .crossEntropy:
            return -zip(outputs, targetOutputs).reduce(0, { (sum, pair) -> Scalar in
                let temp = pair.1 * log(pair.0)
                return sum + temp + (1 - pair.1) * log(1 - pair.0)
            })
            
        case .meanSquared:
            fallthrough
            
        default:
            return 0.5 * zip(outputs, targetOutputs).reduce(0, { (sum, pair) -> Scalar in
                return pow(pair.1 - pair.0, 2)
            })
        }
    }
}

public enum JPSNeuralNetworkActivationFunction: Int
{
    case sigmoid = 0
    case hyperbolicTangent = 1
    
    func derivative(_ activation: Scalar) -> Scalar
    {
        switch self
        {
        case .hyperbolicTangent:
            return (1 - pow(activation, 2))
            
        case .sigmoid:
            fallthrough
            
        default:
            return (activation * (1 - activation))
        }
    }
    
    func activation(_ weightedInput: Scalar) -> Scalar
    {
        switch self
        {
        case .hyperbolicTangent:
            return tanh(weightedInput)
            
        case .sigmoid:
            fallthrough
            
        default:
            return (1 / (1 + exp(-weightedInput)))
        }
    }
}

public class JPSNeuralNetworkNeuron
{
    /**
        Used to generate a single random weight.
    */
    private class func randomWeight(inputCount: Int) -> Scalar
    {
        let range = (1 / sqrt(Scalar(inputCount)))
        let rangeInt = UInt32(2000000 * range)
        let randomDouble = Scalar(arc4random_uniform(rangeInt)) - Scalar(rangeInt / 2)
        return (randomDouble / 1000000)
    }
    
    /**
     Used to generate a vector of random weights.
    */
    public class func randomWeights(inputCount: Int) -> Vector
    {
        var weights = Vector()
        
        for _ in 0..<inputCount
        {
            let weight = JPSNeuralNetworkNeuron.randomWeight(inputCount: inputCount)
            weights.append(weight)
        }
        
        return weights
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert for neural networks or deep learning, so I cannot 
review all aspects of your code. But here is some feedback:

In JPSNeuralNetworkNeuron.swift, some `enum`s are defined with methods
which switch on the possible values of the enumeration, for example

> ```
> func derivative(OfOutput output: Scalar, targetOutput: Scalar) -> Scalar
> {
>     switch self
>     {
>     case .crossEntropy:
>         return (output - targetOutput) / ((1 - output) * output)
>
>     case .meanSquared:
>         fallthrough
>
>     default:
>         return (output - targetOutput)
>     }
> }
> ```

I would remove the `fallthrough` and the `default:` case:

```
func derivative(OfOutput output: Scalar, targetOutput: Scalar) -> Scalar
{
    switch self
    {
    case .crossEntropy:
        return (output - targetOutput) / ((1 - output) * output)

    case .meanSquared:
        return (output - targetOutput)
    }
}
```

That makes the code shorter and safer: If you add another enumeration
value later, the compiler will check that it is covered in the switch
statement.

There are several places where an array is created incrementally
using `append()`, e.g. in JPSNeuralNetworkNeuron.swift:

> ```
> public class func randomWeights(inputCount: Int) -> Vector
> {
>     var weights = Vector()
>
>     for _ in 0..<inputCount
>     {
>         let weight = JPSNeuralNetworkNeuron.randomWeight(inputCount: inputCount)
>         weights.append(weight)
>     }
>
>     return weights
> }
> ```

That can be simplified with `map()`:

```
public class func randomWeights(inputCount: Int) -> Vector
{
    let weights = (0..<inputCount).map { _ in
        JPSNeuralNetworkNeuron.randomWeight(inputCount: inputCount)
    }
    return weights
}
```

That might also increase the performance because the runtime can
allocate the target array with the required size, instead of 
re-sizing it repeatedly.

There are two `feedForward` methods with identical parameters:

> ```
> public class func feedForward(topology: [Int], activationFunction: JPSNeuralNetworkActivationFunction, inputs: Vector, weights: Matrix)
> ```
>
> -> Vector
>
> ```
> private class func feedForward(topology: [Int], activationFunction: JPSNeuralNetworkActivationFunction, inputs:
> ```
>
> Vector, weights: Matrix) -> FeedForwardResult

the former being a wrapper for the latter. But that wrapper method
is not used at all. If you remove it then you can also get rid
of the explicit type annotation in

> let feedForward: FeedForwardResult = JPSNeuralNetwork.feedForward(...)

which is currently required to disambiguate between the two methods.

With regard to class functions or not: There are some "values" which
seem to be actually properties of the neural network, such as
`activationFunction`, `costFunction`, `topology` and perhaps more. At present,
those values are permanently passed around between the class functions.

I would recommend to define those values as (instance) properties of
the type:

```
public class JPSNeuralNetwork
{
    let activationFunction: JPSNeuralNetworkActivationFunction
    let costFunction: JPSNeuralNetworkCostFunction
    let topology: [Int]
    // ...

    init(activationFunction: JPSNeuralNetworkActivationFunction,
         costFunction: JPSNeuralNetworkCostFunction,
         topology: [Int]) {
        self.activationFunction = activationFunction
        self.costFunction = costFunction
        self.topology = topology
    }

    // ...
}
```

and then create an *instance* where you pass those values on
creation:

```
let network = JPSNeuralNetwork(activationFunction: .sigmoid, costFunction: .meanSquared,
                               topology: self.topology)
network.train(delegate: self, ... other parameters)
```

Advantages:

- Many function arguments can be removed. That makes the code 
  better readable and might also improve the performance.
- You can logically separate between constant properties of the
  neural network, variable properties, and parameters which are only
  used in a function (method) call.
- Having an reference (a "handle") to the instance allows for more
  opportunities, e.g. a `cancel` method which aborts the operation.
- You can use the instance itself later to classify input images,
  or perhaps to add additional training cycles (does that make sense?).

Comment: Awesome suggestions. Thank you! Specifically, I didn't think about using array splices (?) along with the map function. That makes much more sense. The reason for the two feedForward functions is because one is public and only returns the output activations and the other returns more information needed privately by the network. Hence, the type alias. Also, I love the idea of a cancel and adding additional training cycles. The idea was to build the system "pure" first. Then, go through and manage state. Is this typically a good way to go about building software? (In your opinion)

Comment: @Jonathan: You are welcome! – It is difficult to give general advice, but in this particular case your "class methods only" approach (which is essentially the same as using global functions only) seems to be a dead end, and rewriting it is more effort than thinking about the right (or approximately right) architecture in the first place.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you mean by dead end? Also, this is just a side project for educational purposes and possibly further use so I wouldn't mind rewriting the whole thing haha.

Comment: @Jonathan: That was perhaps expressed badly. What I mean is that it prevents you from adding features (like "cancel"). A neural network *is* an object and has state, therefore treating is as such is the right thing to do (in my opinion)

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, after testing the network and beginning to expand on it I've noticed what you've mentioned. Well, I'll go back through the code and treat it more like an object rather than a composition of functions and possibly post the modified code. Thank you for your help! Please feel free to let me know if you find anything else!